# Need some help or suggests about programming some groovy script for SoapUI tests

Tags: java, groovy, soapui

I`m working with SoapUI less 1 months. Today I`m got a task related with a cheking image size, which we get in RSS from server. And I must to check all image size in accordance with requirements.
What can I do to make sure that I was able to enter the some sizes of images in the script, and he could verify the conformity of these sizes with a sizes of which we gave from the server? For example, I have a requirement, that the image size must have 200x200 size, and I want to check that the size of some image have this size really.
I'll be very grateful for some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question does not have much information to go on, but here is the basic outline.

Get the `<url/>` sub-element of the [`<image/>`](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html#ltimagegtSubelementOfLtchannelgt) element from RSS, and use:

```
def img = ImageIO.read(url)
```

Now you can call `img.height` and `img.width` to get the size of the image, which you can compare against the expected value (or the values specified in the `<width/>` and `<height/>` sub-elements in the RSS file).